# Angular 13 fileReplacements for main.ts

Tags: angular, angular13

It turns out that my goal is that when I make a custom build, the main.ts is replaced by another main-custom.ts.

I have tried with the fileReplacements but I get the error :

```
main-custom.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig through the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

I have tried to put it in the files section of tsconfig, but I get this error message:

```
"Warning: C:/Users/.../project/src/main.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused. Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig."
```

After all, even if the main-custom.ts is being used in the build, the other main.ts is still included in the compilation and I feel this is a bit dirty.

So any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding your main-custom.ts file under files in your tsconfig.app.json?

Comment: Jakob, yes i tried, but when I do it I get this warning: "Warning: C:/Users/.../project/src/main.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.". It would be nice if there was a solution that did not give me any warning.